# Retrieving data from flat JSON into HTML

Tags: html, json, node.js, botframework

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159487/microsoft-bot-framework-saving-the-chat-history), I have managed to save my chatbot's conversation history as a flat json file. I would now like to see the contents of the json in the `index.html` file. I tried using this code in my html, but I get a blank page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>    
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('chathistory.json', function(json) {
            console.log(json); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

**My chatbot conversation logging code:**

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
       //console.log(session.message.text);
       test="\r\nUSER: "+session.message.text;
       fs.appendFile(filename, test, function(err){     });
       next();
   },

     send: function (event, next) {
        //console.log(event.text);
        test="\r\nBOT: "+event.text;
        fs.appendFile(filename, test, function(err){        });
        next();
    }
});
```

**My chathistory.json file:**

```
USER: hi
BOT: Hi, I am your chatbot.
BOT: What is your name?
USER: Anish
BOT: Hello, Anish. How may I help you today?
```

How can I see this data in my index.html page?

Comment: ok you get a blank page, but did you check the Developers Console to see if your json was read in properly from the text file? You are getting a blank page because your javascript isnt doing anything with the json data.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `console.log(json)` so you are not writing anything in the HTML; try doing `document.write(json)`.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I still get a blank page. Do you think rest of my html code is correct?

Comment: are you sure you are hitting that line? maybe the getJson is failing?

Comment: `chathistory.json` is a file which has been created in the same folder of the bot, along with app.js, package.json, etc. So do I still need to mention the whole path or does chathistory.json work fine? Also, the file is quite flat without any json formatting. More like free text. Will that cause any issues?